# File appears with ls File butnot ls Folder

Tags: linux, ls

simple question.

I have a folder with many files, I'm interested in a particular one, let's call it FILE.

When I run

```
ls FILE
```

The path of the file is printed.

However, let's say this file and many others is contained in a FOLDER. when I run:

```
ls FOLDER
```

I see many files but not FILE.

How do I debug this behavior? What are the possible causes?

Extra info: FILE is a `zip` file and I am able to unzip it and see it's content.

Comment: Can you show us the _exact_ commands and their output?

Answer (score 1):

Possible reasons

1. Incorrect folder name may be you are doing `ls Folder` instead of `ls FOLDER`
2. The FILE may be a hidden one, please check using `ls -alh ./Folder`
3. Permissions: `ls -l FOLDER/FILE`